# Chances in a multiple choice test

Tags: probability

Let's say there are **5 multiple choice questions**, with the answers **A**, **B** or **C**. The chance that you get it correct by random guessing would be $\frac13$. I need **at least 3** correct answers to pass the test. What would the chance be, with random guessing, that I pass the test?

A friend of mine told me that the chance was about $0.045$, using the *binomcdf*-function on the calculator, but this seems too small for me. Is this really the answer, or have we done it wrong?

Comment: Let's work it out together: at least 3 means 3, 4 or 5 correct answers. Do you know to calculate the probability of getting 3 correct answers? And 4? And 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is wrong [edited]. Let's work it out together, see the comments on the question above.

Comment: For 3 correct answers, the chance would be $(\frac13)^3\cdot(\frac23)^2$, right?

Comment: No, and I noticed my answer was also wrong. :-P. This is the chance of having 4 correct answers in a certain order, e.g., right, right, right, wrong, wrong. But you also have to consider the other cases, e.g., RRWRW, etc. How many cases like that do you have?

Comment: That would be $5 \choose 3$

Comment: yes, so multiply $(\frac13)^3\cdot(\frac23)^2$ by $5 \choose 3$ to get the chance for 3 correct answers.

Comment: Do the same for 4 and 5 correct answers. The answer by Danijel follows the same idea, but instead of counting 3, 4 and 5 correct answers, he counted 0, 1 and 2 correct answers and got the complement.

Comment: That gives me $0.210$, thanks for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to vote up or down for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, now we have Binomial distribution with parameters $n=5$ and $p=1/3$, which is the chance of getting the right answer. We need at least 3 of them.

$$P\{B\geq3\}=1-P\{B<3\}=1-(P\{B=0\}+P\{B=1\}+P\{B=2\}), $$

where $$P\{B=k\}={5 \choose k}({\frac{1}{3}})^{k}({\frac{2}{3}})^{5-k}.  $$

**EDIT:**

And if you want exact result it is something about $0.209876...$ or just $\frac{17}{81}$